# Are DLCs and a Boss all that's added for Sotfs? (PS3)

Tags: dark-souls-2, version-differences, dark-souls-2-sotfs

I purchased DS2 Sotfs (PS3) but the DLCs and Aldia are the only things that have changed. Are the pursuers in Lost Bastille and the Heide Knights in Heide's Tower Of Flame only added for certain devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PS4 and PS3 versions are almost identical apart from three things:

1. New Enemy Placement, Gameplay Design
2. Graphics and Performance Upgrade
3. More Online Players

The above things are what's included in the PS4 release.

So the pursuer should appear in Lost Bastille and the Heide Knights should be in Heide's Tower of Flame. [Heide Knight wiki](http://darksouls.wikia.com/wiki/Heide_Knight)

[Graph showing all differences in platform](http://playstationna.i.lithium.com/t5/image/serverpage/image-id/387781i62B2CC5FD5A2EE30/image-size/original?v=v2&px=-1)